# set wordpress search term in cookie

Tags: php, wordpress, search, cookies

When a user types in a term in a wordpress search input and submits the form, I would like to store the term as as a cookie so i can recall it on a different page.  I found some code on the codex but I cannot figure out how to alter it to make it work.  Im fairly new to PHP and Wordpress, help is much appreciated.

```
// add cookie
add_action('init', 'my_setcookie');

// my_setcookie() set the cookie on the domain and directory WP is installed on
function my_setcookie(){
 $searchcookie = esc_attr( get_search_query() );
 $path = parse_url(get_option('siteurl'), PHP_URL_PATH);
 $host = parse_url(get_option('siteurl'), PHP_URL_HOST);
 $expiry = strtotime('+1 month');

setcookie('my_cookie_name_1', $searchcookie, $expiry, $path, $host);

/* more cookies */
setcookie('my_cookie_name_2', 'my_cookie_value_2', $expiry, $path, $host);
}
```

Comment: The above code will create a cookie called "my_cookie_name_1" and set the term searched for, as its value. On the page where you want to use the value just use `<?php echo $_COOKIE["my_cookie_name_1"]; ?>`

Comment: I just tried that, and the value is not appearing.  I dont think the cookie is being stored.  Chrome devtools arent showing the cookie being stored as a resource.  Its good to know how to call the cookie though, when i get this figured out, so thanks!

Comment: It may be worth noting that the above code is in my functions.php file

Comment: I just solved this on my own.  I was focusing too hard on a way to do this with Wordpress.  Javascript can do this much easier...